# run a php file with an endless loop

Tags: php, linux, perl

I am trying to run this php script in my linux based server.

```
$today      = strtotime("today");
$tommorow   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1day",$today));
$today      = date("Y-m-d");

//Endless loop because the data here updates around the clock 
while(1){

    while (time() <= strtotime("$tommorw 8:00PM")){

            sleep(30);
            flush();
        }

    }//end 24 h loop
    //save the file as a date file and delete it's content


    //move on to the next day   
    $today      = strtotime("today");
    $tommorow   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1day",$today)); 

}//end of endless loop
```

and it workes fine if I run it from a simple browser (ofcourse it stops working when I close it).

I am trying to run it through a perl script

```
chdir("mydir");
exec('indices.php');  #tryed also system("php indices.php");
```

and run the perl script like so

```
./PROMadadim.pl >> ./PROMadadim.log &
```

but it doesn't work when I am trying to run it from the server.

Comment: its called a Daemon, google "php Daemon"

Comment: Why do you say "it doesn't work"? What specifically occurs? Is it running but functions incorrectly? Does it not run at all (`ps -A` shows nothing)?

Comment: Setup a cron job. Having infinite loop is not nearly remotely adviced.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the code your probably better to setup a CRON job. If your server doesn't support CRON then you could try adding...

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

or try adding -q to the php command like so:

```
php -q /home/user/example.php
```